# Program gets stuck attempting to create NNTP connection

Tags: python, nntp

My program starts a connection to a usenet server like this:

```
s = nntplib.NNTP(self.nserver, 119, self.nuser, self.npass)
```

But sometimes there's a problem. The connection is not made and the program waits for a response indefinitely.

How can I make it check for a timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the proper solution, but try to set a timeout to the socket module :

```
import socket

orig_timeout = socket.getdefaulttimeout(timeout)
socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)

s = nntplib.NNTP(self.nserver, 119, self.nuser, self.npass)

socket.setdefaulttimeout(orig_timeout)
```